# fetching repo from CLI

Tags: api, github

As stated [here](http://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/), fetching a private repo from the CLI would result in a `404` http status, due to the lack of authenticating.  However, this is only the case if my repo is set to private, which in this case it is set to public.  Whenever I attempt to fetch information regarding my public repo, I still receive a `404`.

If the repo is set to public, shouldn't I be able to `curl -i https://api.github.com/BrandonMercer/blogger` without receiving a `404`?

Comment: `https://api.github.com/BrandonMercer/blogger` is an URI that git could use, you should use `git clone https://api.github.com/BrandonMercer/blogger` to clone your project.

Comment: I'm not attempting to clone it, I just want the api to return the repo information via CLI, instead of a `404` status.

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to retrieve repo information from the CLI, use `curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repo-name>` for public repos.  Private repos require authentication via token or the `-u` flag.